# Interactive Ipython Notebooks on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, jupyter-notebook

I am currently trying to make python tutorials and host them using an ipython notebook on a Heroku site. The problem is that ipython notebooks are static when uploaded. I am trying to make it such that the user can use the notebook interactively (such as print outputs). I also dont want the output from their notebooks to be saved permanently on the Heroku website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have 2 issues do deal with :

- interactive notebooks
- "read only" notebooks (do not save the modifications)

---

For issue 1, you need to use a jupyter (the new IPython name for notebooks) server. Only showing the notebook is not enough because you need a server to "understand" and execute the modifications. See : http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html

I am not familiar with Heroku, after googling 2s I found this : https://github.com/pl31/heroku-jupyter which was able to deploy a working Jupyter server on a demo heroku machine.

---

According to me, issue 2 is more difficult to solve.

When the "learners" will change the notebook, the modifications will be applied to the notebook file (.ipnb) so the modifications will be persistent... This is not want you want.

You could try some tricks using file permissions to prevent the kernel to save the file, but I think it would only crash the kernel...

Moreover it asks several user-interaction problems, for instance what if I lose my internet connection ? Will I loose my work ? Why ? Is this what I really want as a learner ?

For this, the best solution is to provide a user access to the notebook / a worksapce where she can save her progression, but it is more work than just deploy a jupyter server. As an example, see databricks.com (the first (only) one that come to mind, not necessary the best).

(As a remark, it seems that the multi user mode is already implemented : https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

---

I would like to add a last remark about the security of the server. Letting stranger access a server with an embedded shell sound like a bad idea if you are not prepared for the consequences. I would suggest you to see how you can put each user's jupyter session in a "jail" / container, anything that works in Heroku.